# Add link to gt table elements without additional text

Tags: r, r-markdown, gt

I want to add links to my gt table cells as shown:

```
raw_dat <- mtcars[1:15, ] %>% rownames_to_column(var = "id") %>% select(id, mpg)
tibble(
  name = raw_dat$id,
  link = paste(raw_dat$mpg, "And <a href = 'https://www.cars.com//'>here</a>")) %>%
  mutate(link = map(link, gt::html)) %>%
  gt
```

Results:

[image]

How can I make the link fall on the `raw_dat$mpg` and not have any additional text after it. So the desired output is by clicking on the `raw_dat$mpg` cell, you can be taken to cars.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(gt)
raw_dat <- mtcars[1:15, ] %>% rownames_to_column(var = "id") %>% select(id, mpg)
df <- tibble(
  name = raw_dat$id,
  link =  'https://www.cars.com//')

df %>%
  mutate(link = sprintf('<p><a href = "%s">%s</a>', link, raw_dat$mpg),
         link = map(link, gt::html)) %>%
  gt
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you can construct a string using `sprintf` (not tested, obviously).

```r
link = sprintf("<a href = 'https://www.cars.com'>%s</a>", raw_dat$mpg)
```

Answer (score 1):

Taking together both existing solution. Here is a straight `tidyverse` approach:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gt)

mtcars %>% 
  slice(1:15) %>% 
  rownames_to_column("name") %>% 
  mutate(link =  'https://www.cars.com//',
         link = sprintf('<p><a href = "%s">%s</a>', link, raw_dat$mpg),
         link = map(link, gt::html)) %>%
  select(name, link) %>% 
  gt
```

[image]

.....
.....